# new to YOLOV5 , Is there a way to Determine weather the object is upside down or not in YOLOV5?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I am new to YOLOV5 Object Detection but I have followed a tutorial and trained a model and it worked.
Is there is any way to know the orientation of the object (if it is upside down of not )?
if anyone can guide me will be grateful

Comment: The computer doesn't know what is right-side up, right?  If the object has a distinct outline, you can probably train a neural net to classify its orientation.

Comment: you mean to train another model, may please explain more ?

Comment: Well, YOLO should be able to do it, as long as you have models of your object in different orientations.  You just make those different classes in your model.